# Wrapping a function around a session variable in a PHP/MySQL logout form

Tags: php, mysql, function, session, authentication

I have a member/admin website that uses a logout form to show my user as `Welcome, Administrator, pat@tires.com`. Well, I would like to use a function to wrap around the `loginName` which is in a session so that the `@tires.com` drops off of the name when it is shown.

Below is my logout form and the function I want to use. Right now, when I try to use it, it just gives me an error message and doesn't drop the `@tires.com` off of the name.

Logout form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="logoutform.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Logout</legend>

    <?php
      echo "Welcome, ";
      echo $_SESSION['level']. ", ";
      echo $_SESSION['loginName'];
    ?>

    <br /> <br/> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="logout"/>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The function I want to use:

```
function get_name($results) {
  $name = preg_split("/@/", $results['email']);
  $name = ucfirst($name[0]);
  return $name;
}
```

> ERROR: when wrapping the function around the session and loginName:
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'email' in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\tire\includes\functions.php on line 49
>   A
>
> ERROR using the exact function get_name($results);
>   Notice: Undefined variable: results in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\tire\admin\home.php on line 58

Comment: Please write the error message

Comment: @Ahmad Samilo, I added the error I get - This is from wrapping the function around the session and variable together.

Comment: @AhmadSamilo, I added the error I get when I just use the get_name($results). It's only a undefined variable error. Any help is appreciated. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your function and add plain value for email
EX:

```
  <?php    
     $email="test@gmail.com";
    function get_name($email) {
        $name = preg_split("/@/", $email);
        $name = ucfirst($name[0]);
        return $name;
     }   

          ?>
```

Then print the result , if you have no error that mean the value of email was assigned 
in wrong way , just double check and your problem will solve .

Comment: I can see  how this would work, but I need the value to be from the form that was logged in. I need it to be the logged in name which is in the $results['email']. How can I get the results there? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Please try var_dump( $results['email']); die(); 
and let me know the result

Comment: It says it's null, but I have the email showing up so I know it isn't null. The email shows up like this: Welcome, Administrator, angie@tires.com

Comment: that is the problem , the value is null .
can you please tell how you assign the value ?

Comment: function connect($loginName) {
 global $db;
 $query = "SELECT email, level, password FROM members WHERE email = '$loginName'";
 $result = $db->query($query);
 $results = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 return $results;
}

Comment: please var_dumb for $result array

Comment: This one says it is NULL too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71985/discussion-between-regina-shepherd-riddle-and-ahmad-samilo).